# Аналогия событию focusout

Tags: jquery

**Можно ли сделать аналогию событию focusout для списка ul > li ?**

У меня есть тег UL c вложенными LI, всё это сделано в виде выпадающего списка, при клике на элементе показывается список всех LI, всё работает только focusout не корректно работает.

**Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным ?**

Пример тут: [jquery/test30.html](http://www.saitadmin.ru/faili_na_razdacu/jquery/test30.html)

Comment: код приведите, где некорректно отрабатывает.

Comment: `<ul>` не может содержать div по стандарту, и где там focusout или что-то еще,

Comment: Про стандарт: хорошо, буду знать. Вставил focusout как у меня это было

Comment: Вообще мне бы услышать просто совет, как можно сделать эти списки похожими на обычный салект как бы. Вся загвоздка в их закрытии, надо чтобы при клике в любом месте у тега убирался класс 'show'

Comment: Просто совет - на велосипед выдано более 25000 патентов - не надо его изобретать. Есть готовое решение - https://github.com/claviska/jquery-selectBox

Comment: вот так я бы это сделал, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2Y2Er/

Comment: IMPORTANT
---
I first started working on this plugin nearly two years ago, but I never ended up using it in production. Because of this, I can't prioritize further development for it and therefore the project is suffering.

If someone is interested in officially taking it over, please let me know.

For a more current, feature-rich plugin, consider using http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Comment: Спасибо eicto, немного помогло разобраться